# How do I parse a word between two elements?and extract it to database

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

let me brief there is a file (it might be anything sgml,xml,sgml etc).i will give that file as input and read the file using c#..so the job is now that i know that there are certain tags where in  between this data is present...so the point is i have to scan that line by line like pattern matching and  extract the data which is present in between tags ,...so please help me getting this ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a word between two elements?and extract it ,(input file is sgml)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565208/how-do-i-parse-a-word-between-two-elementsand-extract-it-input-file-is-sgml) . How many times you are going to ask the same question?

Comment: diff people understand the question in diff way....

Comment: If you are trying to do pattern matching why don't you use Regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think if file is some how in xml format you can use XPath to traverse/manipulate its elements..

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Regards.